# Access to **private** variables of a class in Python

Tags: variables, private

I understand that Python does not explicitly support private variables in a class. However, please consider the following program:

```
class AClass(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__x = x



class BClass(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__x = x
# _____________________________________________________________________________

aClass = AClass(10)
bClass = BClass(10)

aClass.__x = 15
print (aClass.__x)


##bClass.__x = 20
print (bClass.__x)
```

The program above, will produce following error:
AttributeError: 'BClass' object has no attribute '__x'

But, if the second last line of code is uncommented, it will execute without an error.

If someone can please clarify what appears to be an inconsistency and if there is a PEP that explains this behaviour, I would appreciate a pointer to it.

Best regards.

BD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because variables starting with a dunder are name mangled to "protect" them. If you examine the dictionary of `bClass`, you'll see:

```
>>> print(bClass.__dict__)
{'_BClass__x': 10, '__x': 20}
```

The `_BClass__x` (I'll call this the object variable) was created by the object itself, hence its mangled name. The `__x` was created *outside* of the class<sup>(a)</sup> which is why it has a non-mangled name, and therefore why you can access it with just `__x`.

To access the object variable for both types, you can use:

```
print (aClass._AClass__x)
print (bClass._BClass__x)
```

But I'm not sure how reliable that is. I *am* sure that it's something you probably shouldn't be doing however, since it breaks encapsulation :-)

In fact, though I said the mangling was done by the object, I want to make sure you understand it's not done when an object is instantiated. The actual mangling happens when the code is *compiled,* which you can see if you disassemble:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(AClass)
Disassembly of __init__:
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              4 STORE_ATTR               0 (_AClass__x)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `STORE_ATTR` bytecode actually knows to use a mangled name.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> And it is very much *distinct* from the object variable, as you'll find to your distress when you later try to use `__x` within a member function and find it hasn't been changed by your code outside :-)

Comment: I did know that I had checked that using ``` print (dir(bClass))```. It is the inconsistency in access that I cannot understand: a write access is allowed unconditonaly and a read access becomes possible after a write is performed.

Comment: @user816270: A read is only valid after a write because, outside of the class, `__x` doesn't actually *exist* until you create it (only `_<classname>__x` exists). It's no different to trying `print(varname)` before you have executed `varname = "something"`.